# Container WordPress closes without error message (Docker, Bitnami, MySQL)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, bitnami, synology

I have a problem creating containers.
I want to use the console to create containers automatically.
This works so far only it stops the container WordPress after a short time.

I guess the problem is related to MySQl because the automatic creation with MariaDB already worked. But with MySQL I can't get it to work.

The Container WordPress closes without any error message. The only message I got in Synology is that it closes. ( It is shown in the picture)

Would be great if someone could help me.

Greetings

```
version: '3.7'
  services:
  db:
    image: bitnami/mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_USER=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=duerrundsteidle
  wordpress:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 4000:443
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wpdb
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=user
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=passowrd
  phpmyadmin:
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 12000:80
      - 14000:443
    volumes:
      - ./phpmyadmin
```

[SynologyError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxSs3.png)

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  (Please edit the question to add it as text, not as an image and not behind a link.)  Indentation in the `docker-compose.yml` file  matters, can you correct this as well?

Comment: The problem is that there is shown now error. As you can see in the picture the container wordpress closes. While the build also no error occurs. (I can change the picture tomorrow)

Comment: Hi, Bitnami Engineer here. I see that you are mounting folders from your filesystem but they have /bitnami as mount points. Does it work when you don't specify volumes at all? This is important so we can see if there's an issue with the persistence or not.

Comment: Thanks for your held.
I've tested it withourt the lines volume but there is alwaqys the same error.
The container will be created but the container wordpess closes.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: bitnami/mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_USER=duerrundsteidle
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=duerrundsteidle
  wordpress:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
     - db
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 4000:443
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wpdb
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=user
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=passowrd
  phpmyadmin:
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 12000:80
      - 14000:443
```

This is the code I´ve tested last time.